# Duda sobre el uso de Threads, AsyncTask y Handler

Tags: java, android, android-studio, hilos, asynctask

En este código hacen uso de *threads*, *handlers* y `AsyncTask`, lo que no entiendo es porque se hace uso de los 3 y no solo de *threads* o *handlers*, ¿Cual es la diferencia?, En el código tengo comentado las razones y el porque se usaban desde mi perspectiva, pero todavía estoy muy confundido

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Wifi_Information extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView infoview;
    EditText e1;
    EditText e2;
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wifi__information);
        Button getinfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bwifiinfo);
        getinfo.setOnClickListener(this);
        e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bmensaje);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Thread mythread = new Thread(new MyServer());
        mythread.start();

        infoview = findViewById(R.id.infoView);
    }
    //Esta clase lo que hace es simplemente crear el servidor
    //Y ponerlo disponible
    //Runnable solo es una interfaz que necesita para instanciar un hilo para contenerlo
    class MyServer implements Runnable {

        ServerSocket ss;
        Socket mysocket;
        DataInputStream dis;

        String message;
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ss = new ServerSocket(8080);
                //Nos sirve para ejecutar una accion especifica desde un hilo que estemos ejecutando sobre un view
                //Aqui no entiendo porque uso ese handler

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Esperando al cliente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                while (true) {
                    //El codigo se queda en la siguiente linea hasta que una conexion a nuestro servidor se estableca

                    mysocket = ss.accept();
                    dis = new DataInputStream(mysocket.getInputStream());
                    message = dis.readUTF();

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            tv.append("ANDROID:" + message);
                            tv.append("\n");
                        }
                    });

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    //La clase async task nos permite crear acciones en el hilo principal, pero no acceder a sus componentes
    //ente los caracteres <> ponemos los tipos de variables que maneja y devuelve
    //datos que pasaremos al comenzar la tarea, parametros que necesitareos al actualizar la Interfaz+
    //Dato que devolveremos una vez terminada la tarea
    //Usamos async task para poder actualizar la interfaz
    //Porque la interfaz no acepta llamadas desde otros hilos que no sea el suyo
    //Solo para tareas mas pequeñas
    //Y no entiendo porque para esta operacion uso async task
    class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        Socket s;
        DataOutputStream dos;
        String ip, message;

        @Override
        //Esto es un hilo en segundo plano
        //Se encarga de realizar la tarea en segundo plano
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            ip = params[0];
            message = params[1];
            //El ip es la direccion ip del servidor y el puerto al cual esta siendo excuchado

            try {
                //Aqui el socket recibe de parametros el ip de destino y el puerto del servidor
                s = new Socket(ip, 8080);
                dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeUTF(message);
                dos.close();

            } catch (IOException E) {
                E.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void GetWifiInformation() {
        infoview.setText(" ");
        WifiManager wifimng = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifimng.getConnectionInfo();
        if (isWifiConected()) {
            infoview.append("SSID: " + wifiInfo.getSSID() + "\n");
            infoview.append("BSSID(ACCESS POINT): " + wifiInfo.getBSSID() + "\n");
            infoview.append("LINK SPEED: " + String.valueOf(wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed()) + "\n");
            //No funciona en android M o superior
            infoview.append("YOUR MAC ADDRESS: " + this.getMacAddress() + "\n");
            infoview.append("IP ADDRESS: " + getIpAddress() + "\n");
            infoview.append("DNS 1: " + getDns(1) + "\n");
            infoview.append("DNS 2: " + getDns(2) + "\n");
            infoview.append("CHANNEL: " + getChannel(wifiInfo.getFrequency()));

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NO WIFI CONECTION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case (R.id.bwifiinfo): {
                BackgroundTask b = new BackgroundTask();
                //Verificar que el ip sea el mismo
                b.execute(e1.getText().toString(), e2.getText().toString());

                break;
            }

            default: {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la clase `MyServer`:

```
class MyServer implements Runnable {
    ...

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Esperando al cliente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Si no se utilizara el *handler* para mostrar el `Toast` se arrojaria una excepcion del tipo:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't toast on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Al ser ejecutado a traves de un *handler* el codigo se ejecuta en el `Looper` asociado al *thread* y el error no ocurre.

Mas abajo no era necesario utilizar `AsyncTask` para la comunicacion con sockets, se pudo haber utilizado tambien un *thread*, no hay interaccion alguna con la interfaz de usuario.